# laravel 5 authenticate problems

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

My authenticate system does not work (with laravel 5.1). Can you please help me ? I am a beginner in Laravel , certainly I forgot something, but I do not know what.

I have this response :

> FatalErrorException in personne.php line 10: Class
>   'App\Models\Eloquent' not found

My auth.php :

```
 'driver' => 'eloquent',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

// 'model' => App\User::class,
    'model' => 'App\Models\personne',
```

My personne class :

```
 namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class personne extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


    protected $table = 'personne';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_personne';
    public $timestamps = false; // pour ne pas que laravel update lui même les champs dates de la table


    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

etc....
```

My controller :

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Auth;

class AuthentificationController extends Controller {
```

EDIT : 
I changed the personne class like that :

```
    namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class personne extends Model implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

and now the error is :

FatalErrorException in personne.php line 13: Interface 'App\Models\UserInterface' not found

Comment: PHP can't find the class Eloquent in App\Models, it's probably Laravels one you're after. You need to include the Illuminate Eloquent class like you do with the others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Eloquent Model class :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class personne extends Model implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
// ...
```

And please respect OOP directives and use Capital letter for the first letter in your class name `Personne`

You are using Laravel 5.1 so here's how you use eloquent models : [Eloquent Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

And you can use the authentication system that Laravel provides out of the box, [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

The class 'personne' must start with :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class Personne extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract

{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
```

andnow all is working fine. 
dominique